# Create a job board website like Monster Jobs

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, xhtml

Hey guy's,
I have a customer who wants a website to get company's to post their available jobs and work like Monster Jobs. I have no clue what technologies are needed to make a Monster.com clone. I know that I'll need HTML, CSS, and jQuery... maybe PHP and MySQL? Please point me in the right direction, since we will probably have to hire some extra hands and I need to know what I need to get this project started. Thanks.

Comment: This question is far too subjective and general to be answered here. There is no real way to answer it. If you don't know already which of these technologies to use, then you should seriously reconsider taking on the project. It's much like me saying "Someone wants me to build them a house, I need wood and stuff right?"

Comment: Um... OK? I don't want to know the exact technologies that are used (I can find that on my own). I like your comment @SLC, but yeah I developed a simple website for this client and currently act as their web admin as well. This is why they want me to oversee this project. I am more than capable to build the front end, I just need to know what to look for a back end developer for this particular project. Sorry this type of development question should not be asked here, I'll try to post it (enter correct place here) next time. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two areas:

**Client Side**

- Javascript/Jquery
- HTML
- CSS

**Server Side**

- A database
- A server side scripting language

People will debate for ever as to which language/database is better, but there is no right answer (except Access, don't use Access for a backend DB!), pick the language that the person developing it is most experienced/comfortable in.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need all those technologies. HTML and CSS, etc. are needed to design the appearance and basic behavior of the site. But you'll also need a database and more significant code running on the server.

You have a number of choices for the code running on the server. My preference is ASP.NET and SQL Server. PHP and MySQL is another choice. And there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Renzo, I guess you can use the technologies you're more familiar with to create such a job board.
Indeed, you need a DB and a bunch of web forms to post jobs from the backend or to answer to a job post submitting a resumé.

Using the languages you're more familiar with, it will lead to release a MVP in very brief.